# Impala JDBC connector : different architecture?

Tags: cloudera, impala

On the Web Site ([www](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/downloads/connectors/impala/jdbc/impala-jdbc-v2-5-5.html)), there are different downloads for different OS and 32 vs 64 bits. Does it mean this JDBC driver is platform specific ? Looking at the JARs it seems they're all the same with no binary involved.

Comment: Also don't have for Ubuntu. By the way, I'm connecting in the Impala with Hive Driver.